# Display 2d image with Vuforia image target

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens

Following this quick start guide. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/vuforia_get_started.html. I am trying to display a 2D image on target image instead of 3D model.

If I drag the 2D image from assets folder onto the Unity scene, it just covers the target image.

Dragging the 2D image on top of ImageTarget object in hierarchy does nothing.

How can I setup a 2D image to display when target image is detected?

Answer (score 0):

You know you have to put the 2d-image as a child? Pls read how to use image targets, "You can do this by simply adding your assets as children of the target in the scene hierarchy" → [Documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity.html).